# vuejs component does not render if I import printjs

Tags: vue.js, printjs

I am trying to print pdf file generated of a form, `printjs` but when I import printjs no vuejs component load at all, the title in the browser show up but component is not rendered.

```
import printJS from 'printjs'
```

then later I call the function:

```
methods: {
    printSlip: function(){
        printJS('docs/printjs.pdf')
    }
```

when button is clicked:

```
<input type="submit" v-on:click="printSlip" value="Print" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the printjs.pdf file can be found/path is correct?
Do you see some error in the console?